# Tangent space to an affine variety $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ isomorphic to affine space $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{A}^n = \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ be n-affine over the field of complex numbers.

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ be an irreducible, non-constant polynomial, and let $X = \mathbb{V}(f)$ be the vanishing set of $f$.

For a point $p = (p_1, \cdots, p_n)\in X$, define the tangent space $$T_pX := \{q = (q_1, \cdots, q_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n \ |\ \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_p (q_i - p_i) = 0\}.$$

A point $p \in X$ is *singular* if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_p = 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, and *non-singular* otherwise.

Why is it that if $p\in X$ is non-singular, then $T_pX \simeq \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are not using Schemes. If $p$ is non-singular then the matrix $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} ~\dots~ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$ has full rank, so its kernel (which is exactly $T_p X - p$ is a $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n = \mathbb{A}^n$ (and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My linear algebra needs some serious brushing up. As I remember, if $A \in M_n(K)$ is a matrix, then the kernel of A $$\text{ker}(A) = \{ v \in K^n \ |\ Av = 0\}.$$ If we fix a vector $p\in K^n$, then is this set $$\{v \in K^n \ |\ A(p-v) = 0\}$$ also a kernel of some matrix?

Comment: You're right. You have to move the kernel by $p$. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Wait, $p$ will not be in the kernel of $A$ in general (that wouldn't make any sene since $p$ is a point and not a vector).

Comment: In our case $p$ is an element of the tangent space, so $$ T_pX = \{q \in \mathbb{A}^n \ |\ (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} , \cdots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})|_p(q- p) = 0 \} = \text{ker}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} , \cdots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})|_p $$

Comment: @3891780 $q - p$ is in the kernel, but you only want $q$ for the tangent space.

Comment: It works because for any $p\in \text{ker}(A)$,  $$\text{ker}(A) = \{v \ | \ Av = 0\} = \{v \ |\ A(p - v) = 0\}.$$ This is because if $p\in \text{ker}(A)$, then $$Av = 0 \iff A(p - v) = 0.$$

Comment: @3891780 $p$ must not be in the kernel of $A$. Think of a circle centered around the origin.

Comment: But in our case $p \in T_pX$

Comment: Yes, but that's because if you set $q = p$ then $q - p = 0 \in \ker A $

Comment: Yes you're right. We don't know if $p$ belongs to ker$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \cdots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})|_p,$ right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87806/discussion-between-0x539-and-3891780).